# Comparing $\frac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!}$ to $\frac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}$

Tags: inequality, factorial, gamma-function

For $n \ge 0$, is $\dfrac{\left(n+\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}{n!} > \dfrac{(2n)!}{\left(2n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor\right)!}$

I will consider an answer using the gamma function!  I have used the floor function in my question only because I was not clear how to make the argument using the gamma function.

I believe the answer is yes.  Here's my argument:

- For all $n$, $\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{3}\right\rfloor \ge 2\left\lfloor\frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor$
- So, there are $2$ terms $(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+\frac{2n}{3})$ for every $1$ term of $(2n)(2n-1)\dots(2n-\frac{n}{3}+1)$ and since $(n+1)(n+2)=n^2+3n+2 > 2n$ where $(n+1)*(n+2)$ is the least product and $2n$ is the greatest value.

---

Edit:  I am open to an answer with the gamma function.

Comment: How are you interpreting the factorial of a non-integer?

Comment: I am applying a floor function.  I will add that detail to the question.  Will that make a difference here?

Comment: It makes a difference in that your terms are otherwise *undefined*. It is hard to prove anything about undefined terms.

Comment: Great point.  I agree about the importance of being exact.  I just meant that once I define it as I should, will it change the result.  Apologies if my question was unclear.  I will edit the question to correct the ambiguity.  :-)

Comment: The previous version of the question was fine, it is enough to state that $m!$ means $\Gamma(m+1)$ for a non-integer $m$. I would propose a rollback, this version is unnecessarily uglier and more difficult to prove.

Comment: The previous version was a different question, though, and perhaps not what was meant.

Comment: Umberto, Jack, thank you both!  I have updated the question.  To Umberto's point, the question introduced ambiguity that a better stated question would have avoided.  I will keep this in mind for future questions.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are stating that
$$ 2\log\Gamma\left(\frac{5}{3}n+1\right)>\log\Gamma(2n+1)+\log\Gamma(n+1)\tag{1}$$
holds for any $n\geq 0$. In order to prove it is enough to show that

$$ 2\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+\frac{5}{3}n}\right)> \sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+2n}\right)+\sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{m+n}\right)\tag{2}$$
then integrate both sides of $(2)$ with respect to the $n$ variable. $(2)$ is equivalent to
$$ \sum_{m\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{m+2n}+\frac{1}{m+n}-\frac{2}{m+\frac{5}{3}n}\right)>0 \tag{3} $$
but that is trivial since the main term of $(3)$ can be represented as $\frac{n (m+3 n)}{(m+n) (m+2 n) (3 m+5 n)}>0$.

Comment: Awesome!  I reallly appreciate the analysis.

Comment: @LarryFreeman: thank you, but in order to prevent downvotes, I have to say this answer replies to the previous version of the question, not involving any $\left\lfloor \cdot\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Got it.  I will add a note to the question so that your answer is 100% .  I thought that the floor version was easier.  I luke tour analysis much better!